# WordPress DIrectory & Server Organization

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a dedicated IP and server space for a specific WordPress project (ex: 555.555.555.55) and within my root folder for that IP I have a WordPress install within it's own directory (555.555.555.55/wordpress) because I didn't want to crowd my root folder with all those WP files.

I'm about ready to move my WordPress install completely to the root folder so it's viewable with the IP and without the /wordpress extension.. Is there an easier way to redirect my IP to the WordPress folder without showing the /wordpress extension? I was going to work through the .htaccess file to redirect any requests to the IP to go to the WP folder but if the user navigated through the site, the URL would still show the /wordpress extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory